# Listeners on JxSearchPanel

Tags: java, swingx

Do you have a solution to implement a listener with jXSearchPanel to be able to execute some code when users adds text on the search field?

I searched within javadoc but I can't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about JXSearchPanel, but I would guess the panel uses (or extends) a regular JTextField. If this is the cause then you can just add a DocumentListener to the Document of the text field.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Document Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for a working examples.